# iOS8 - Accesing built in camera editing features

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, camera

I am creating an app in which I want to store an image taken from the iOS device's camera and then allow the user to crop a particular section of it. After cropping/rotating I want to store a final version of the image.

I have tried and written code to access the camera and store that image in an object by using this reference.
https://github.com/jquave/CameraTutorial/

Can I use built-in crop/rotate iOS 8 features in my application using any Obj-C or Swift API?